# Obtener la longitud de un array mediante una función en C++

Tags: c++, array

Si yo intento mostrar la longitud de un array en *C++*, mediante la función `sizeof`, muestra correctamente el resultado, que en este caso es 8.

```
int main()
{
    int array_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
    int longitud=sizeof(array_enteros)/sizeof(*array_enteros);
    cout<<longitud<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que no me gusta es que hay que ingresar la palabra `array_enteros` dos veces para conocer la longitud, y por esto, sería mejor obtenerla mediante una función.

```
int obtener_longitud_array(int* array_enteros)
{
    return sizeof(array_enteros)/sizeof(*array_enteros);
}
int main()
{
    int array_caracteres_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
    int longitud=obtener_longitud_array(array_caracteres_enteros);
    cout<<longitud<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

En este caso, me devuelve 1, que es un valor diferente.

¿Habrá algún problema en los parámetros de la función?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Problema.

El problema de tu función `obtener_longitud_array` es que pierdes la información del tamaño al pasar el parámetro `array_enteros` (además de que sólo puedes calcular el tamaño de arreglos de enteros).

#### Explicación.

C++ es un lenguaje de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte) y [estático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos#Tipado_est.C3.A1tico), esto significa que no puedes cambiar de tipo en tiempo de ejecución y que todo tiene un tipo concreto (nada de tipos comodín como [el `object` de](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)).

Pero en ocasiones C++ da la sensación de tener tipado dinámico porque existen transformaciones implícitas de tipos. Una de estas transformaciones implícitas es la transformación de arreglo a puntero, según [el estándar de C++ [image]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 4.2 Conversión de arreglo-a-puntero
>
> Un valor del lado derecho o izquierdo te tipo **“arreglo de `N` `T`” o “arreglo de extensión desconocida de `T`” puede ser convertido a** un valor puro del lado derecho de tipo **“puntero a `T`”**. **El resultado es un puntero al primer elemento del arreglo**.

Arreglo de `N` `T` sería:

```
T arreglo[N];
```

Donde `T` sería un tipo cualquiera y `N` un valor cualquiera.

Arreglo de extensión desconocida de `T` sería:

```
T arreglo[] = { ... }
```

Donde `T` sería un tipo cualquiera, y es el tipo de arreglo que estás usando en tu ejemplo.

Al pasar el arreglo `array_enteros` a la función `obtener_longitud_array`, el arreglo pasa por la conversión mencionada ([§4.2 [image]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)) y pierde su tipo original. El tipo original del arreglo contiene el tamaño.

#### Tamaño como parte del tipo.

Un arreglo de `N` `T` o un arreglo de extensión desconocida de `T` contienen el tamaño como parte de su tipo:

```
/* Tipo int       */ int i;
/* Tipo int[10]   */ int a[10];
/* Tipo double[3] */ double d[] { .0, .1, .2 };
```

Es por esto que, puede ser detectado el tamaño usando sobrecargas de función:

```
void f(int[10]) { std::cout << "Arreglo 10.\n"; }
void f(int)     { std::cout << "Entero.\n"; }

f(a); // Muestra "Arreglo 10"
f(i); // Muestra "Entero"
f(d); // Error de compilacion, no existe funcion que acepte double[3]
```

Así que tu función `obtener_longitud_array` podría ser una plantilla que obtuviese el tamaño del arreglo de esta manera:

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::size_t obtener_longitud_array(int[N]) { return N; }
```

O podrías generalizarlo para tipos diferentes a entero [como ha hecho Dolmenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74499/2742). Pero en lugar de re-inventar la rueda yo usaría la utilidad [`std::extent`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) perteneciente a la cabecera [`<type_traits>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) de la librería estándar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int array_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
    std::cout << std::extent_v<decltype(array_enteros)> << '\n'; // 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tengo que ponerme en serio con C++11; ya va siendo hora, digo yo. +1.

Comment: @Dólmenes `std::extent_v` es de C++14 ;P

Comment: yo creía que dentro de los `<>` de una plantilla debía ir necesariamente un tipo de dato y ese tipo era el que cambiaba entre instancias diferentes de la misma plantilla; pero cuando tú colocas `<size_t N>` entonces lo que cambia es un dato de tipo `size_t` ¿verdad?

Comment: @AliRojas Un parámetro de plantilla puede ser un tipo de dato, un valor, una plantilla o un pack de tipos o valores

Answer (score 11):

EL problema es que la funcion no recibe un array, sino un puntero, el cual tiene size 1, los punteros funcionan como arrays pero no son lo mismo.

Puedes usar un macro para resolver este problema

```
#define GetSize(array_enteros) (sizeof(array_enteros)/sizeof(*(array_enteros)))
```

y despues usar GetSize como si fuera una funcion

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define GetSize(array_enteros) (sizeof(array_enteros)/sizeof(*(array_enteros)))

int main()
{
  int array_caracteres_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
  int longitud=GetSize(array_caracteres_enteros);
  cout<<longitud<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ya que estas en C++, puedes usar *la forma C++ de hacer las cosas*: usando `template`.

#### 1. C++11, `constexpr`:

Compila sin problemas con

> `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic`

```
template< typename T > inline constexpr size_t Countof( const T (&) ) { return 0; }
template< typename T, size_t S > inline constexpr size_t Countof( const T (&)[S] ) { return S; }
```

#### 2. C++98, **sin** `constexpr`:

Lo único que cambia es, justamente, la eliminación de dicha palabra clave.

Compila sin problemas con

> `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++98 -pedantic`

```
template< typename T > inline size_t Countof( const T (&) ) { return 0; }
template< typename T, size_t S > inline size_t Countof( const T (&)[S] ) { return S; }
```

#### Código de prueba:

Válido para C++98 y superiores:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template< typename T > inline size_t Countof( const T (&) ) { return 0; }
template< typename T, size_t S > inline size_t Countof( const T (&)[S] ) { return S; }

int main( void ) {
  int v0;
  int v1[1];
  int v2[2];
  int v3[ ] = { 1, 2, 3 };

  cout << "Countof( v0 ): " << Countof( v0 ) << "\n";
  cout << "Countof( v1 ): " << Countof( v1 ) << "\n";
  cout << "Countof( v2 ): " << Countof( v2 ) << "\n";
  cout << "Countof( v3 ): " << Countof( v3 ) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

La salida es:

> Countof( v0 ): 0
>   Countof( v1 ): 1
>   Countof( v2 ): 2
>   Countof( v3 ): 3

Como ves, distingue entre *arreglos* y *no-arreglos*. En el primer caso, devuelve el número de elementos (tanto si se indico al declarar la variable como si se omitió). En el segundo, devuelve `0`.

#### ¿ Porqué 2 versiones ?

La primera `template` **no** es estrictamente necesaria. Es para evitar errores si lo usas en variables **que no sean** *arreglos*. Hace uso de la característica [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) del lenguaje: cuando se intenta *instanciar* una plantilla y los parámetros *no coinciden*, **no** se genera un error, sino que sigue buscando otras versiones de la `template` que **si** coincidan.

En nuestro código de prueba, si omitimos la primera versión de la platilla

```
// template< typename T > inline size_t Countof( const T (&) ) { return 0; }
```

Mi g++ *escupe* lo siguiente:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Countof(int&)’
>      cout << "Countof( v0 ): " << Countof( v0 ) << "\n";
>                                               ^
>   note: candidate: template constexpr size_t Countof(const T (&)[S])
>    template< typename T, size_t S > inline constexpr size_t Countof( const T (&)[S] ) { return S; }
>                                                            ^~~~~~~
>   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   note:   mismatched types ‘const T [S]’ and ‘int’
>      cout << "Countof( v0 ): " << Countof( v0 ) << "\n";

Sin embargo, con las 2 versiones, el compilador lo intenta con **ambas**, y, dependiendo del caso, lo conseguirá con una u otra. Esos *intentos* son los que nos permiten realizar la discriminación entre variables *normales* y *arreglos*.

Comment: En ningún lugar ni de la especificación ni de la documentación oficial se dice que templates personalizadas "son la manera" de hacerlo en C++, las templates son solamente una herramienta más. De hecho la solución ofrecida sobre-complica muchísimo un problema que bien podría solucionarse trivialmente con std::vector el cual es parte integral de C++.

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de hacerlo, usando C++11 y la `template std::remove_all_extents< T >`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T > constexpr ::std::size_t countof( const T & ) noexcept {
  return sizeof( T ) / sizeof( typename ::std::remove_all_extents< T >::type );
}
```

> If T is a multidimensional array of some type X, provides the member typedef type equal to X, otherwise type is T.

Lo cual, en traducción *muy mucho* libre por mi parte, viene a decir:

> Si `T` es una formación multidimensional del tipo `X`, proporciona un `typedef type` igual al tipo `X`; en otro caso, dicho `typedef` lo es al tipo `T`.

- Si `T` es de la forma `tipo[]...` (con cualquier número de dimensiones`, obtenemos el tipo base`T`.
- Si `T` **no es** de la forma `tipo[]...`, obtenemos igualmente el tipo `T`.

Esto puede usarse para obtener el tamaño de cualquier variable, sea o no una *formación*: si lo es, podemos obtener el tamaño de su tipo base; si no lo es, obtenemos igualmente el tamaño del tipo base. Por lo tanto, en cualquier caso, nos basta con dividir el tamaño de la variable entre el `typedef type` obtenido de la `template`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template< typename T > constexpr size_t countof( const T & ) noexcept {
  return sizeof( T ) / sizeof( typename remove_all_extents< T >::type );
}

int main( ) {
  int a1;
  int a2[2];
  int a3[3][3];
  char str[] = "Hola mundo !";

  cout << "countof( a1 ) " << countof( a1 ) << "\n";
  cout << "countof( a2 ) " << countof( a2 ) << "\n";
  cout << "countof( a2 ) " << countof( a3 ) << "\n";
  cout << "countof( str ) " << countof( str ) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Muestra lo siguiente:

> countof( a1 ) 1
>   countof( a2 ) 2
>   countof( a2 ) 9
>   countof( str ) 13

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int longitud_array (int x, int y)
{
    int la = x / y;
    return la;
}
int main ()
{
    int array_enteros[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2};
    int longitud = longitud_array(sizeof(array_enteros), sizeof(array_enteros[0]));
    cout << "La dimensión del array es de " << longitud << " y sus posiciones van del 0 al " << longitud-1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira las otras respuestas que me dieron, ya está solucionado... Mi pregunta es cómo hacer una función que obtenga la longitud, en vez de eso estás declarando una variable que obtiene la longitud.

Comment: Ok, usando el mismo pensamiento de la función anterior usando la variable, se puede conseguir la función facilmente. Modifico sobre el anterior el código.