# ¿Por qué se puede decir int array_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'}; si C++ es fuertemente tipado?

Tags: c++, array, tipos

Viendo esta la publicación [Como saber la longitud de un array en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74456/obtener-la-longitud-de-un-array-mediante-una-funci%C3%B3n-en-c) me encuentro con un array de este tipo:

```
int array_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
```

¿No se supone que C++ es fuertemente tipado?

Se supone que solo debe recibir enteros como tal, no caracteres de enteros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como tu indicas C++ es un lenguaje de tipado fuerte, pero en el ejemplo del link lo que se ingreso en el arreglo fueron **caracteres** en un **arreglo de enteros**, entonces ¿Cómo puede ser posible?, pues no es tan loco si le das una vuelta, un carácter tiene un equiválete en entero. Esto lo puedes comprobar mirando una tabla ASCII.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla podrás comprobar que los caracteres en decimal tienen un valor equivalente.

**EDIT**

Se me olvidaba mencionar que el compilador infiere que lo que tu quieres almacenar es el valor entero correspondiente al caracter. Si en cambio estuviera entre comillas dobles, el compilador debería darte un error.

**FIN EDIT**

También es posible comprobarlo con el siguiente código basado en tu ejemplo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
    int aux = sizeof(array_enteros)/4;
    
    cout<<"Tamaño array: "<<aux<<"\n\rContenido array:\n\r";
    
    for(int x = 0; x < aux; x++) {
        cout<<array_enteros[x]<<", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Donde la salida es la siguiente:

```
Tamaño array: 8                                                                                                                                                                    
Contenido array:                                                                                                                                                                   
57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50,
```

Como ves, los valores coinciden con los de la tabla.

Comment: No es una tabla ASCII. ASCII solo tiene caracteres 0 a 127. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII Hay mucha información errónea al respecto en Internet. Por favor, no ayudes difundirlo.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. El [ASCII extendido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_extendido) tiene de 0 a 255.

Comment: @MrDave1999 El problema con "el ASCII extendido" es, "el" ASCII extendido no existe. Hay muchos ASCII extendidos. Ninguna de estas tablas es mejor que la otra. La página de wikipedia muestra una tabla diferente de la que se muestra en esta respuesta.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. La tabla que muestra la wikipedia es la misma que muestra esta respuesta (sin incluir el ASCII Extendido). Solo que la fuente de dicha tabla se encuentra en este enlace: [elcodigoascii](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) e incluye el ASCII Extendido de la IBM. Solo porque la tabla muestra el ASCII extendido no la hace incorrecta.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. se agradece la acotación, de igual manera si la tabla es o no es, creo que no aporta a la respuesta como tal, done lo que me interesaba aclarar era que ese caracter tenia un equivalente en decimal.

De igual manera en defensa de la tabla, creo que esta seccionada y no se presenta como un todo, especifica una sección como ASCII extendido.

Comment: @MrDave1999 "sin incluir el ASCII Extendido" ese es el punto. Cada fuente muestra la parte extendida de manera diferente. Lo que significa que es mejor no usar el término. Si quieres hablar sobre página 437, llámalo "página 437", no "ASCII extendido". Si quieres hablar sobre código de la IBM PC, llámalo "código de la IBM PC", no "ASCII extendido". Ellos dos son diferentes, no los llames del mismo nombre. Por cierto, nadie debería usar nada de esto en 2020. Usa UTF-8. Lo siento, es una manía mía :)

Comment: @DarkFrostnight No quise decir que tu respuesta es incorrecta. Es solo una aclaración de la terminología.

Comment: Se entiende y se agradece todo el conocimiento extra. :D

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Que C++ no es fuertemente tipado?

C++ es fortísimamente tipado:

---

[image]

---

Pero no te han explicado toda la historia. En concreto no te han hablado de los tipos aritméticos ni de la promoción aritmética.

Una posible clasificación de los tipos de C++ puede ser entre aritméticos (números) y no aritméticos (cualquier cosa que no sea un número), los tipos que son considerados aritméticos te sorprenderán:

- El tipo booleano.

  - `bool`.
- **Todos los tipos de carácter**:

  - `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `wchar_t`, `char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`.
- Todos los tipos de enteros:

  - `short`, `short int`, `signed short`, `signed short int`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned short int`, `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, `unsigned`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `long int`, `signed long`, `signed long int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long int`, `long long`, `long long int`, `signed long long`, `signed long long int`, `unsigned long long` y `unsigned long long int`.
- Todos los tipos de coma flotante.

  - `float`, `double`, `long double`.

Los tipos aritméticos tienen una especial relación entre ellos: son implícitamente convertibles entre si siguiendo unas normas conocidas como *promoción aritmética* que son bastante extensas pero que si quieres puedes consultar en [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112440/2742), si no quieres  leer dicho hilo basta con saber que cuando dos tipos diferentes forman parte de una operación:

- Si un tipo es entero y  otro es de coma flotante, el tipos entero se convierte implícitamente en el tipo de coma flotante.
- Si un tipo es más pequeño que el otro, el tipo de menor tamaño se convierte implícitamente en el tipo de mayor tamaño.

---

Así que ¿Qué está pasando aquí?:

```
int array_enteros[]={'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};
```

1. Cualquier valor (de un dígito) entre comillas simples `''` es un literal de carácter.
2. Los caracteres son tipos aritméticos.
3. Se convierte el carácter (`char`) a entero (`int`).